# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, sockets

I'd made a windows service remote server program that will able to communicate to a Windows CE device(as remote client) listening for a broadcast request, save a request to file, examine it and send back the requested file content being trace. I've implemented it in (c#) asynchronous transfer mode. It is working properly, but just 2 days ago I've encountered this socket exception:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)`

this is my code it points to the exception

```
     public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
     { 

          ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();
          try
          {
              long connection_number;

              //finish accept
              Socket s;
              s = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
              connection.socket = s.EndAccept(result);

              connection.socket.Blocking = false;

              connection.Buffer = new byte[10000]; //1kb buffer minimum


     orionIP = ((IPEndPoint)connection.socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
               lock (connections) connections.Add(connection);
             IPHostEntry hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(orionIP);
               machineName = hostName.HostName;
               lock (connections) connections.Add(connection);
                //count client connected
              connection_number = Interlocked.Increment(ref connection_count);

              //start receive -> error here 
   connection.socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length,
                  SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), connection);

            //start new accept 
             serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), result.AsyncState);

          }//end try 
          catch (SocketException ex)
          { //later log files for error events  - > ex.SocketErrorCode
              string path = "eventlogs.txt";
              //create error log files to write error here 
              File.WriteAllText(path, ex.ToString());
              CloseConnection(connection);
          }
          catch (Exception exp)
          {
              string path = "eventlogs.txt";
              //create error log files to write error here 
              File.WriteAllText(path, exp.ToString());
              CloseConnection(connection);
              // log error file later ("Socket Exception:" + exp.ToString());
          }
     }
```

I have no major revision made to it when the exception occurred. I followed all the instruction along with others encountering the same problem such as turn off the firewall, `maxusePort`, check network connections and devices if properly configured, buffer size. I also check the race condition and `WSAECONNABORTED` issues i might dealing with.

Can anyone relates to this problem give me some additional solutions? Any additional knowledge will be a great help .

**Receive callback**

```
     private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
     {
         //06.10 added thread for writing in the file 

         //added part review () 
         //getemp file 
         string pathwrite = CreateTmpFile();//"streamdata.txt";
    ConnectionInfo connection = (ConnectionInfo)result.AsyncState;
         try
            { 

             int bytesRead = connection.socket.EndReceive(result);

             if (bytesRead > 0)
             {
                 lock (serverlock)
                 {
                     connection.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(connection.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                 }

                 lock (connections)
                 {
                     foreach (ConnectionInfo conn in connections)
                     {
                         if (connection != conn)
                         {
             conn.socket.Send(connection.Buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);

                         }
                     }
                 }
   connection.socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), connection);        
             }
             else
             {
                 string strContent = connection.sb.ToString();
                 File.WriteAllText(pathwrite, strContent);
                AccessData();
                 CloseConnection(connection);
             }

         }//end try 

         catch(SocketException ex){
             string path = "eventlogs2.txt";
             //create error log files to write error here 
             File.WriteAllText(path, ex.ToString());
        // CloseConnection(connection);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             string path = "eventlogs2.txt";
             //create error log files to write error here 
             File.WriteAllText(path, ex.ToString());
          //   CloseConnection(connection);
         }


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not accept new connections if there is a network error with the currently accepted connection. Move the BeginAccept to a separate try/catch.

```
public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{ 

    ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();
    try
    {
        long connection_number;

        Socket s;
        s = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        connection.socket = s.EndAccept(result);
        connection.socket.Blocking = false;
        connection.Buffer = new byte[10000]; //1kb buffer minimum


        orionIP = ((IPEndPoint)connection.socket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
        lock (connections) connections.Add(connection);
        IPHostEntry hostName = Dns.GetHostEntry(orionIP);
        machineName = hostName.HostName;
        lock (connections) connections.Add(connection);
        connection_number = Interlocked.Increment(ref connection_count);

        connection.socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length,
        SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), connection);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        string path = "eventlogs.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(path, ex.ToString());
        CloseConnection(connection);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        string path = "eventlogs.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(path, exp.ToString());
        CloseConnection(connection);
    }

    try
    {
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), result.AsyncState);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //failed to accept. shut down service.
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes you've suggest but still the socket exceptions still exist. It's just happened to receive this exception when I detached the device to the host machine, i'm actually using a hyperterminal to test the send request functionality. It seems that the connection is established and the client can connect but when transmitting some data back to the server it closes the connection and loses other data packets.

Comment: then I do not thing that the problem is in the AcceptCallback but in the receive callback

Comment: what might be wrong in the receive callback. this is my code:

Comment: sorry i just have some internet connection problem. here again is my code for my receive callback. 

  try
                { 
  ConnectionInfo connection = (ConnectionInfo)result.AsyncState;
                 int bytesRead = connection.socket.EndReceive(result);

                 if (bytesRead > 0)
                 {
                     lock (serverlock)
                     {
                         connection.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(connection.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                     }

Comment: lock (connections)
               {
  foreach (ConnectionInfo conn in connections)
    {
   if (connection != conn)
      {
   conn.socket.Send(connection.Buffer, bytesRead, SocketFlags.None);
 }
    }
     }
         connection.socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                     // new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), connection);
                     connection.socket.BeginReceive(connection.Buffer, 0, connection.Buffer.Length, 0,
                     new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), connection);   }

Comment: else
   {
    string strContent = connection.sb.ToString();
     File.WriteAllText(pathwrite, strContent);
       AccessData();
       CloseConnection(connection);
  }
           
  }

   catch(SocketException ex){

            CloseConnection(connection);
                              
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
                
            CloseConnection(connection);
                      }

         }

Comment: What can be the possible error in the receive callback, i observe in my client host that instead of sending data as whole stream it sends it one line of data at a time. what might be the trouble ? im really confuse.

Comment: that is impossible to read. update your question with the code.

Comment: i had my code posted as answer, comments limits characters i cannot post it as whole . thanks

Comment: @user3747532. You should remove the connection if the receive callback throwns an exception